# Estou tentando criar um esqueminha de apagar os itens de uma lista. O dado que será apagado o input() que vai determinar

Tags: python-3.x, lista, input

```
objetos = ["1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6"]

escolha_cliente = input("ESCOLHA OS ITENS OU DIGITE FIM PARA NAO ESCOLHER 
NENHUM: ")
if escolha_cliente.isdigit():
    escolha_cliente = int(escolha_cliente)

if escolha_cliente == "fim":
    print("FIM!")

if escolha_cliente in objetos:
    del(objetos[escolha_cliente])

print(objetos)
```

Comment: Se você tem uma lista de strings, nunca a sua condição `escolha_cliente in objetos` será satisfeita, uma vez que `escolha_cliente` será um `int`.

Comment: O que devo fazer nesse caso? Acabei de substituir por slice...

Comment: O que pretende fazer? Se o usuário digitar 3, qual deverá ser o resultado?

Comment: O resultado devera retornar a lista "objetos", porém sem o 3, nesse caso.

Comment: Mas qual 3? O valor 3 ou a posição 3?

Comment: Valor 3, posição 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada em listas e a diferença entre **pop**, **remove** e **del**.
[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520492/difference-between-del-remove-and-pop-on-lists/11520540), por exemplo.

No seu caso, como voce quer retirar da lista pelo ***valor*** selecionado, então deve usar o **remove**...

Segue um exemplo basico:

```
objetos = ["1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6"]
print(objetos)

escolha_cliente = input("ESCOLHA OS ITENS OU DIGITE FIM PARA NAO ESCOLHER NENHUM: ")
escolha_cliente_string = str(escolha_cliente) # Não é necessário fazer o cast para String
print(escolha_cliente_string)

objetos.remove(escolha_cliente_string)
print(objetos)
```

Lembrando que ***remove*** irá remover apenas o **primeiro** elemento encontrado, ou seja, se tiver mais de um, os outros permanecerão na lista.

Além disso, não fiz nenhum tratamento para o caso em que o usuário digita um valor que não existe na lista.

Comment: Obs.: converter `escolha_cliente` para `str` é desnecessário uma vez que o retorno de `input` **sempre** é uma *string*.

Comment: Verdade @Woss, erro meu

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Woss e @Vinicius!!